# How to classify with multinomial logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I want to fit a multinomial logistic regression model in R and use it for classification. In all sources I see people use the logit models for calculating the probabilities, but I want the model to predict the classes of the dependent variable which is a categorical variable that indicates 4 Life zones. The independent variables are 36 continuous climatic variables. I need to create the model that can be used to predict the life zone classes using the continuous predictor variables I have. I was wondering what the best way is to do this in R. Thank You! I greatly appreciate your time.

Azad

Comment: Check out `glmnet` with `family='multinomial'`. More here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf

Comment: Hello, thank you! I was reading through this before but I cant find how to take the equation for prediction. I want to make a formula to calculate the predicted response levels or life zones for any values of the predictor variables.

Comment: You can build your model on the training set with `glmnet` and then use the `predict` function on your test set.

Comment: Thank you! My test set is a group of ascii files each representing one of the predictor variables. I mean I want to predict the map of the response variable based on the model I make using the predictor ascii files as inputs. Can I use the model made in glmnet with AsciiGridPredict function in yaImpute package to predict the dependent variable map?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could always try it out to see whether it works. Good luck!